Minimize max-norm of 3x3 orthogonal matrix
What is the value of
$$ \min_{O\in \mathrm{O}(3)} ||O||_{\max} = \min_{O \in \mathrm{O}(3)} \max_{ij} |o_{ij}|$$
or are there non-trivial bounds known to this quantity?
Here, the minimum is over 3x3 real orthogonal matrices $O$ and $||O||_{max}$ denotes the max-norm of $O$, i.e. largest entry in absolute value.
A trivial lower bound is $$\min_{O\in \mathrm{O}(3)} ||O||_{\max} > \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$$ but according to this linked question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/351790/are-n-times-n-special-orthogonal-matrices-all-the-entries-of-which-have-the
, this lower bound is not attainable for 3x3 matrices. So, how close we can get to this?

PyTorch simulation results the lower bound might be $\frac{2}{3}$. Hopefully someone can validate this.

The matrix is $\begin{pmatrix}
\frac {-2} 3 & \frac 2 3 & \frac {-1} 3 \
\frac 2 3 & \frac 1 3 & \frac {-2} 3 \
\frac {-1} 3 & \frac {-2} 3 & \frac {-2} 3
\end{pmatrix}$. This might be useful in proving the lower bound.

The trivial lower bound in this post is for infinity norm. But the quantity in question is max norm. For max norm, the trivial lower bound is actually $\frac1 3$.
